# How to Test in Django the Numbers of Querysets Returned by a CBV

Tags: django, testing

For a real-estate app I have a search form and a class-based ListView that shows only the objects (properties) that match the search query from the form:

```
# views.py

from django.views.generic import ListView
from django.db.models import Q

from .models import Property
from .forms import PropertyForm

class ListPageView(ListView):
    template_name = 'property_list.html'
    model = Property

    def get_queryset(self):
        plz = self.request.GET.get('plz')
        rooms = self.request.GET.get('rooms')
        if plz and not rooms:
            object_list = Property.objects.filter(zip_code__exact=plz)
        elif rooms and not plz:
            object_list = Property.objects.filter(rooms__exact=rooms)
        elif plz and rooms:
            object_list = Property.objects.filter(
                Q(zip_code__icontains=plz) & Q(rooms__exact=rooms)
            )
        else:
            object_list = self.model.objects.none()

        return object_list
```

### Tests

I wrote a test to check the logic of my view. I was able to write a test that checks if the queryset returns nothing:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.db.models import Q

from na_mi.models import Property


class ListPageViewTest(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        Property.objects.bulk_create(
            [Property(zip_code=4054,rooms=1),
             Property(zip_code=4132,rooms=4),
             Property(zip_code=4132,rooms=4),
             Property(zip_code=4132,rooms=3),
             Property(zip_code=4056,rooms=1)]
        )

    # tests if the queryset returns nothing   
    def test_view_no_match(self):
        response = self.client.get('/list/')
        self.assertContains(response, 'Sorry, no search result')
```

### Question: How can I test my view if it returns the right number of querysets?

I want to have a test that ensures that the right number of querysets is returned.
Something like that (pseudo code).

```
    def test_view_show_zip_code_only(self):
        response = self.client.get('/list/?plz=4054&rooms=&title=/')
        self.assertContains(response.NUMBER_OF_QUERYSETS_RETURNED, '1')
```

Here it should only return one queryset, because only one database record that maches the query (`plz=4054`) exists in the database and nothing else is requested.

I found the [`TransactionTestCase.assertNumQueries(num, func, *args, **kwargs)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TransactionTestCase.assertNumQueries) function but I don't want to test my queryset I want to test my view.

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a start, there is only one queryset here, containing a number of model instances; I guess it is the number of instances you care about.

The answer is that the response from the test client gives you access to the context that was used to render it; you can then assert on the length of the object list:

```
object_list = response.context['object_list']
self.assertEqual(object_list.count(), 1)
```

Comment: Yes, you're right. I confused querysets with modelinstances. It's indeed the number of instances that are returned I care about.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Do you have a link to a resource where I can learn more about this? That would be great.

Comment: [Testing responses](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/testing/tools/#testing-responses)

Comment: That's great. Thank you!